# Dimensions of mass in terms of Length and Time

Tags: electromagnetism, units, dimensional-analysis, si-units, unit-conversion

From Maxwell's Treaties on Electricity and Magnetism:
For acceleration due to attraction of a mass m at a distance r is by the Newtonian Law m/(r^2). Suppose this attraction to act fro a very small time t on a body at rest, and to cause it to describe a space s,
s = 1/2*(m/r^2)*t^2
whence m = 2*(r^2)(s)/(t^2) and since s and r are both lengths and t is a time the dimensions of m are [L^3 T^-2].

Is this true? Can mass be described in terms of length and time as Maxwell describes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system

Comment: It seem to me that Maxwell's reasoning only works if inertial mass is identical to gravitational mass.  Non-relativistic classical physics can't make that claim.

Answer (score 0):

Normally mass is treated as a unit that is independent of length and time and the acceleration due to gravity is written $Gm/r^2$, not $m/r^2$ where $G$ is Newton’s gravitational constant with appropriate dimensions. If you insist on having $G=1$ with no dimensions, then mass (or length, or time) loses its independence as a unit.

This is similar to how, if you set $c=1$, length and time cannot be independent units.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this true? Can mass be described in terms of length and time as
>   Maxwell describes?

You'd better read section 5 of vol. I from its very beginning. Maxwell
is describing several ways of defining the unit of mass. It's a very
instructive page, especially if you think of its date (1873). Among
others he outlines the astronomical system, where (Maxwell's words)
"the unit of mass is defined with respect to its attractive power".
Your quotation follows.

It's almost obvious that I don't agree with @Garyp's comment. It's true
that

> Maxwell's reasoning only works if inertial mass is identical to
>   gravitational mass.

But I totally disagree with the following

> Non-relativistic classical physics can't make that claim.

The opposite is true. General relativity takes that as an axiom
(principle of equivalence). Newtonian physics simply takes it as an
*extremely well founded* experimental fact.